# How to call external class into AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a method inside an external javascript class.i'm trying to call that method inside to my controller function.(there is a toggle button in my view,when toggle is `checked`,i want to call external method)

**Controller**

```
myApp.factory('PushClient', ['', function() {

    return PushClient;
}]);

myApp.controller('MainController', function (PushClient,$scope, $rootScope, $http, $window){

$rootScope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(event) {

    if(event.target.checked){

      var PushClient = new PushClient();
      PushClient.mypush();
    }else {

    }
  };

}
```

**external PushClient class**

```
class PushClient {
constructor(....){...}
       ............

    mypush(){
        alert("hiiii");
    }
}
```

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Answer (score 2):

you can use like this

```
Class:

class Client {

   get Name() {
    return this.mypush();
  }
    mypush(){
        return "Imran";
    }

}
```

Factory :

```
app.factory('PushClient', [ function() {


  return new Client();

}]);
```

Angular App :

```
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl",['$scope','PushClient' ,function($scope,PushClient) {

    $scope.products = ["Milk", "Bread", "Cheese",PushClient.Name];


}]);
```

and HTML file :

```
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
     <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in products">{{x}}</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
```

Comment: How did you import the file class Client ?